# Jquery Slider in Php / Laravel Blade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to use the variable `$currentSliderCount`, which holds the current slider value
in the second statement of my for loop, instead of `$chCount` I want to pass `$currentSliderCount`
how to accomplish this?

I use the jquery ui slider.

```
// filename = slider.blade.php

$currentSliderCount = $('#number_of_chapters').val();

for(var i = 0; i < $currentSliderCount; i++) {
    // php loop blade syntax

}

@for ($i = 0; $i < $chCount; $i++)
    $('#sliderAppendNumCh').append('...');
@endfor
```

I tried it with ajax like this:

```
    change : function(e, slider) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/",
            data: slider.value,
            success: function() {

                // add chapters
                $('#sliderAppendNumCh').empty();
                for(var i = 0; i < $currentSliderCount; i++) {

                }

                @for ($i = 0; $i < $chCount; $i++)
                    $('#sliderAppendNumCh').append('...');
                @endfor
            }
        }
    });
    },
```

But I do not know how I can use that value from ajax.

Comment: Why not just use `$currentSliderCount` inside the for loop then?

Comment: because it is a js variable / declared with jquery

Comment: So what youre trying to do is passing a Javascript varaible to PHP?

Comment: @Jessedegans ye I want to get the current slider value in my php loop

Comment: Thats impossible because the php code is Server side code and is there for executed before your client side code(Javascript)

Comment: Tells us about the bigger picture and we may solve your problem in another way :)

Comment: @Jessedegans ok so I have products which I can create and edit/update, inside my edit modus I catch the data from my db like names for example, these names are shown in a js ui slider. Now if I edit project 1 which has 2 names, these 2 names are listed in my slider. Now if I want to move the slider to the left (the slider has a value of 1 now) it shall only show the first name.

Comment: @J.Alan Okay i just saw your explanation after i posted my answer will update my answer asap!

Answer (score 1):

## Server & client side

Web development is all about communication. In this case, communication between two (2) parties, over the HTTP protocol:

- The **Server** - This party is responsible for **serving** pages. (PHP in your case)
- The **Client** - This party *requests* pages from the **Server**, and displays them to the user. In most cases, the client is a **web browser** (html/ css / JavaScript).

Each side's programming, refers to code which runs at the specific machine, the server's or the client's.

So the code on your server(PHP) doesn't know about your variable on the client side.

As far as i can see you can solve your problem with just using Javascript as followed:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $currentSliderCount; i++) {
    for (var d = 0; d < $currentSliderCount; d++)
      {
        $('#sliderAppendNumCh').append('...');
      }
}
```

Tell us about the bigger picture if this solution doesn't work for you.

## Edit

You could try passing the PHP variable to Javascript like so:

```
var chCount = <?php echo $chCount;?> ;
```

## Edit 2 if you want to use AJAX

First you need to create a new laravel route which returns the ChCount variable. Then do a ajax post and execute code on success like so:

```
change : function(e, slider) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/getChCount",
            data: slider.value,
            success: function(data) {
            // add chapters
            $('#sliderAppendNumCh').empty();
            for(var i = 0; i < $currentSliderCount; i++) {
                for (var d = 0; d < data; d++){
                    $('#sliderAppendNumCh').append('...');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
},
```

Comment: I tried to use it with ajax but I do not know how to access the data value in my slider I updated my question

Comment: @for is a php loop I cant use js there

Comment: @J.Alan i know that. But why do you want to use the PHP for loop if you can just pass the count variable to javascript and then do a javascript for loop?